# Laravel Carbon returns incorrect time

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon, laravel-7

I have an issue with my Laravel app that I'm developing, the returns time is incorrect, I did specify the timezone on both `config/app.php` and `php.ini` file, and I did clear the cache on Laravel using the following commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Also, I restarted my PHP service after changing the timezone in `php.ini` file.
I'm using XAMPP as a server.

**Please note: the only correct time is by using pure php function!**

Anyone can help me in resolving this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time is correct: `Z` at the end of the string means `GMT` (Zulu timezone).

When a Carbon instance is output in a JSON response, it's always converted in the ISO-8601 string and given in GMT timezone, as it's the standard and very recommended way to exchange date information between systems (and so in a JSON API). If you try to pass `new Date('2020-08-20T06:46:34.407Z')` in a browser, you will see that it's automatically converted by the browser into the user timezone.

If you try:

```
Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u')
```

You will see it uses the timezone you chose. And you also make it appear in the output:

```
Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u e')
```

So a system/browser in a different timezone won't mess it up.

Still the best move is to work with UTC on your server side and only use the Asia/Riyadh at the very last moment when you want to display the date on a particular user you know is in this timezone.

I explained it more in details here: https://medium.com/@kylekatarnls/always-use-utc-dates-and-times-8a8200ca3164