# Laravel Attribute Casting DateTime

Tags: laravel, casting

In database, in created_at field I have value "2020-10-04 20:46:14". In model "Entry" i have this code

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:d.m.Y H:i',
];
```

In front app I get value "04.10.2020 18:46". In config/app.php I have timezone config 'timezone' => 'Europe/Berlin'.

Does someone knows what is the problem? Why casts change the time?

Comment: Is there really a problem? One of the values is probably UTC time. Laravel stores dates as UTC, at least in versions prior to L8

Comment: Problem is that Laravel casting function changes datetime from database entry.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue in Laravel 8. In config/app.php I have timezone config America/Argentina/Buenos_Aire, database stored datetime is 2021-03-30 21:38:33 and model cast is returning 2021-03-31 00:38:33

Comment: Did you finally have a fix? I think that converting from UTC to any other format would have to take into account the local time.

Comment: The only solution I had found, is horrible : put 'timezone' => 'UTC' in config file and then the date is incorrect in database but correct in client app 

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use `Carbon` object in your response, its `toJson()` method is being called. The thing is, this method always displays time in `UTC` timezone. In other words, when it's 20:46 in Berlin, in UTC time (in London, for example), it's 18:46.

I agree that this behavior is confusing.

To fix it, either specify your custom format or use your model in response to take advantage of the format in your `$casts`. A quick fix would be:

```php
// your controller method

return [
   'foo' => $entry->created_at->toDateTimeString(),
];
```

You can take a look at this question:
[Laravel Carbon returns incorrect time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62099032/laravel-carbon-returns-incorrect-time)

Answer (score 0):

Your date format for casting looks wrong. It should match the date time format stored in the database:

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s',
];
```

You should format the date differently, when displaying it
`{{ $model->created_at->format('d.m.Y H:i') }}` but the cast should match the original format.